# how to restrict 1 div to not go further than a certain length away from another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have this

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="drag">

    </div>
</div>
```

my jqueryui

```
$(".drag").draggable();
```

So now i can drag the .drag div, how can i code to restrict the drag div to not go beyond 30px distance away from holder? So that if drag div is 30px away from holder div, the drag will have no effect, or basically the drag div will stopped getting "dragged" after it reached a max of 30px away from holder div? Thanks

Comment: Wondering whether any of the answers helped...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var distance;
$(".drag").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui){
        distance = // calculate distance between divs here
        if(distance > 30) return false;
    }
});
```

Refer to **[the events page](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events)** on jQueryui.com

Refer to **[THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u9f465h0/)**. In this, the blue div can be moved around only in a `30px` range from the parent.

Comment: how do i calculate the distance between the divs?

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/u9f465h0/4/

```
var holderPos = {};
holderPos.width = $('.holder').outerWidth(true);
holderPos.height = $('.holder').outerHeight(true);

$('.drag').draggable({ 
  start: function() { 
         $('.drag').draggable({revert:false}); 
  },
 drag: function(event, ui) {
       if(ui.position.left<-30) {
            $('.drag').draggable({revert:true});
            return false;
       }
       else if(ui.position.top<-30) {
            $('.drag').draggable({revert:true});
            return false;
       }
       else if(ui.position.top>(10+holderPos.height)) { 
            $('.drag').draggable({revert:true});  
            return false;
       }             
       else if(ui.position.left>(10+holderPos.width))  {
            $('.drag').draggable({revert:true});
            return false;
       }                                          
 }

});
```

For code above You are able to change speed of reverting:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ revertDuration: 200 });
```

For keep draggable object in div code above You can use only this code beyond:

```
$(".drag").draggable ({ containment : ".holder" });  //for hold drag in div.holder
```

Comment: yep, sorry i had some issue with pc yesterday. just wake up and finishing code and going to work

Comment: i edited a bit and it works fine, do u know how can i reset the position of my .drag back to the initial position?

Comment: done. I updated code with revert. I will try to cut half of code in future to be more sophisticated. ps. if You want to send back object use $( ".selector" ).draggable({ revert: true });

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to wrap the draggable in an absolutely positioned element (*So that it is out of normal flow and won't affect the rest of your layout*) that is larger than `.holder` by `n` pixels (you can achieve by setting it's `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` properties to `-n`) and set it as the [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) of draggable.

```js
$('.drag').draggable({
  containment: ".containment"
});
```

```css
.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px; /*only for demo prpose*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: red;
}
.containment {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  outline: 1px solid dodgerblue; /*only for demo prpose*/
}
.drag {
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="containment">
    <div class="drag"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```